# Отследить перезагрузку страницы Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Реально ли в Vue.js отследить момент перезагрузку страницы в каком либо компоненте ?

У меня есть флаг в базе что с клиентом работает пользователь и когда закрывается модальное окно происходит событие и этот флаг исчезает, но если перезагрузить страницу то флаг естественно зависает

Comment: Что значит зависает? Если нужно хранить какое то состояние на клиенте, вы можете использовать local storage

Comment: В базе храниться флаг, чтоб другие пользователи не могли открыть модальное окно и редактировать клиента, флаги устанавливаются при открытии и закрытии карточки

Comment: Тогда возможно придется использовать сокеты, что бы постоянно держать соединение клиента и сервера

Comment: На сколько мне известно, 100% непосредственно перезагрузку отследить нельзя. Можно периодично слать с клиента запросы и если они давно не приходили то убирать флаг

Comment: Возможно, поможет трекинг события, которое вызывается перед перезагрузкой страницы [window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308361/9435985). Но идея с веб-сокетами / пингами мне нравится больше, это надежнее. И показывать, что редактируется кем-то начиная с такого-то времени, чтобы дать возможность в режиме "форсирования" отредактировать. И есть еще вариант - использовать версионирование, и перед слиянием разруливать конфликты в том же модальном окне.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо совместить две техники.

- Первое, вешаете обработчик события на [window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308336/execute-function-before-refresh/9308361#9308361).
- Второе, используете специальный запрос [beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API), что бы ваш запрос гарантировано (насколько это возможно) дошел до сервера.

Comment: `Второе, используете специальный запрос beacon, что бы ваш запрос гарантировано (насколько это возможно) дошел до сервера`. Сегодня я столкнулся с тем, что не мог разлогиниться 
 сайта. Там используется `navigator.sendBeacon`, который отключен в моем браузере. Поизучав тему, я пришел к выводу, что биконы работают плохо, и лучше их не использовать: https://volument.com/blog/sendbeacon-is-broken хотя это лучше чем AJAX запрос, который вообще не дойдет

Comment: @TotalPusher да, поддержка не во всех браузерах. Но ничего лучше пока что не придумали :(